# Java Apache Commons users

Tags: java, apache-commons

Is there anything in apache commons to convert a Object to byte array, like the following method does?

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(Object obj) throws IOException {
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(obj);
oos.flush();
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
return data;
}
```

[try-finally block closing buffers were omitted to simplify]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In commons lang:

```
SerializationUtils.serialize(Serializable obj)
```